# Not common words

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, slang, offensive-language

Is this a vulgar slang or something? When such a word can be used?

You are a blight.

Is there other words that convey the same clue?

E.g. You are an adversity, an ordeal.

Comment: What did [the dictionary tell you](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blight) and why didn't it help? Where did you hear this term?

Answer (score 1):

Slang?  In the instance of "blight," yes.  Technically, a person cannot be a blight.  But that wouldn't stop me from using it.

Vulgar?  No.

Rude?  Of course.

**Similar sentences:**

- You are the bane of my existence!
- You are a curse! / You are my curse!
- You are a menace!
- You are a nuisance!
- You are a pest!

Comment: Thank you for the amazing suggestions. 
Are all these words above that you wrote considered rude?

Comment: Calling anyone a name is rude.  Pest and nuisance are weak in terms how rude they are.  Menace a bit more.  Curse and bane are rude.  I suspect an argument would begin if I tried to tell you which of curse, bane, and blight is more rude.  Everybody will have a different opinion.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "rude".  Generally, there is something a bit rude about saying these sorts of things to someone, even if you use perfectly acceptable, standard words to do so - which the above are.  But within families or between friends it is often considered acceptable to tell someone they're a pest or a nuisance or a menace..

Comment: @rjpond, that's a good point.  Used sarcastically between friends/family the words are much less rude - if at all.